# "with" in parameter names in Swift initialisers

Tags: cocoa, swift, initialization

This initialiser will cause an error complaining that `"with" is implied for the first parameter of an initialiser; did you mean name?`

```
init(withName: String){

}
```

I'm not sure what this means, if it provides automagically the `withName` external parameter name if I call it name or what...

If I change it to

```
init(name: String){

}
```

any attempt at calling it `init(with: "joe")` or `init(withName: "Joe")` will fail. So I have no idea what the error message is telling me and how I can declare it so I call it `init(withName: "joe")`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In Swift you should not add `with` to the initializer. The initializer should be `init(name:)` and you should call it as `Object(name: "joe")`.

This is because of how Swift methods bridge to ObjC. In ObjC, that initializer will automatically be translated to `initWithName:`. If you named it `init(withName:)` it would become `initWithWithName:`.

Comment: What a terrible feature. :(

Comment: Agreed. The error message is misleading. It should have said "The first parameter of an initializer cannot start with 'with' or else it will look funny when you call it from Objective-C."