# Swift required parameter logic

Tags: swift

In Swift you've got many possible ways to declare a method. You can use the # and _ sign to enforce using parameter names and you can also change the external definition of a parameter.

Somehow the compiler creates an error message for the following method:

```
func createCoffee(withSugar sugar:Bool, andMilk milk:Bool){
}

// Where I want to call it like this:
createCoffee(withSugar:true, andMilk: true)
```

Enforcing me to declare the method as followed:

```
func createCoffee(# sugar:Bool, andMilk milk:Bool){
}

// Resulting in the following way to call it
createCoffee(sugar:true, andMilk: true)
```

A strange thing in this, declaring the method as followed will not result in this enforced com

```
func createCoffee(firstParam sugar:Bool, andMilk milk:Bool){
}

// Resulting in the following way to call it
createCoffee(firstParam:true, andMilk: true)
```

In which way does the compiler decide to allow a different external parameter name?

Comment: I do not get a compiler warning for your first declaration

Comment: The problem is with the parameter starting with "with".  See: http://stackoverflow.com/q/25644127/1630618

Answer (score 1, accepted):

External parameter names are used for greater description. Having the external parameter name as "with_____" makes Swift and XCode see it as redundant. The first parameter technically would always be "with___ *interal parameter name* ". It is purely for syntactical reading ease.

Comment: Got it. Found it with vacawama's comment and this comment is exactly the summary of the answer. Thanks!